# communication between chrome extension (build in React) and Web app (also in React)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension, postmessage

I am building a React web app and a chrome extension. 
I am new to the chrome extension development.

Now the scenario is, I want to send data from chrome extension to web app.
I have tried sending it through url (by opening a same-origin window from chrome extension, with appended data as search parameter).
It works for small amount of data, but gives error on large data.

I have read about using postMessage for sending data, but don't know how to use it in chrome extension developed to React.

```
// This is post message in componentDidMount of chrome extension.
componentDidMount() {
  window.postMessage({type: "FROM_PAGE", text: "My Text1"}, "*")
  // This above line is executed, successfully.
```

Below is for react web app.

```
componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {

      if (event.source != window)
        return;

      if (event.data.type && (event.data.type == "FROM_PAGE")) {
       // We never reach here.

        console.log("Content script received: " + event.data.text);
      }
    }, false)
}
```

We do not receive message in eventListener.
Any suggestions or workaround for sending data will be appreciated.

Manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "HoneyComb",
  "description": "React based Honeycomb extension; a teaching assistant",
  "version": "0.0.0.1",
  "icons": { "128": "icon_128.png" },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "Honeycomb Extension",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["event.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "web_accessible_resources": ["index.css"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.vipkidteachers.com/*"],
      "css": [],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": ["*://*/*"]
}
```

[image: Chrome Extension project structure]

event/src/index.js is empty.
content/src/scripts contains all React code.
popup/src/scripts contains Popup.html and react setup.

Comment: You need a content script to be able to communicate with the web page. If you already have one, show us the `content_scripts` section of manifest.json or if you use executeScript please show the corresponding code. BTW, the problem may be caused by something else entirely so you should debug it in devtools by setting breakpoints on both lines (postMessage and event listener).

Comment: I have edited the message.

Comment: Also, can there be any other method of sending data?

Comment: Yes, a direct method, see [Sending messages from web pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage)